# Convert Django models to normal objects

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-1.6

Disclaimer: I'm coming from PHP, where there's `stdClass`, whereas I don't know if something like that exists in Python.

I'm trying to add a few custom properties to Django models and converting them to JSON using `json.dumps()`. I tried converting them to dicts, but the custom properties don't get converted too. So I'm trying to convert the models to simple objects like PHP's `stdClass`, so that I can add whatever properties I like to it.

Is this possible, or is there an easier way to add custom properties to a model and JSON-encode it?

Comment: Can you show your code and your expected behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want the JSON blob in the database aswell?

If not, then you simple define the properties as usual like normal python methods on the model class, and add the code to export them in your serialiser.

If so, then there is a nice field from [django-extensions](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions) for this

```
from django_extensions.db.fields.json import JSONField
```

You just add the field on your model, and it should handle the conversion to and from python / database representations automagically for you.

Comment: I don't need to save them in the DB, they're only for my JSON output. But I'm not sure I understand what you mean. I add them like normal properties, but they don't get converted to JSON (I'm using `model_to_dict` and then let the Python serializer do the rest).

Comment: you want custom behaviour from the serialiser, so I think you will have to define how you want the output yourself (but you can inherit from a base serialiser, and then just tack on the extra stuff)

Comment: Gotcha. I will do that.